# Как из std::vector удалить диапазон элементов?

Tags: c++, vector

Мне  нужно написать програму которая с вектора удаляет диапазон значений. 
Мой код:

```
std::vector<int> vector = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int begin = 2;
int end = 4;

for (int index = begin; index <= end; )
{
    vector.erase(vector.begin() + index);
}
```

Я так  понимаю мне  нужно удалить с  одного и того же индекса   значения  - количество диапазона . Но  у меня крешится програма. Что не так?

P.S да через  erase  можно  диапазон удалить. но мне свое нужно написать

Новое:

```
for (int index = begin; index <= end; ++index)
{
    vector.erase(vector.begin() + index);
}
```

Comment: Запустите программу под отладчиком и пошагово выполните цикл.

Comment: Ну смотрите сами:

    `for (int index = begin; index <= end; )`

Это же бесконечный цикл! Тогда уж `for (int index = begin; index <= end; ++index)`, а удаляйте элемент с одним и тем же смещением... Но это, конечно, не самый хороший метод удаления, честное слово...

Comment: @Harry так вы имеле введу? смотреть новое ?

Comment: но у меня в  задании  написано  условие  что  один и  тот  же  нужно индекс удалять.  поэтому хз хз

Comment: Конечно нет! Вы удаляете элемент, все остальные сдвигаются - и вы должны удалять опять элемент **на том же месте**. `vector.begin()+begin`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for (int index = begin; index <= end; )
> {
>     vector.erase(vector.begin() + index);
> }
> ```

Здесь ошибка в том, что `index` и `end` в цикле не меняются, поэтому цикл выполняется бесконечно, конечно, пока не упадет приложение.

> ```
> for (int index = begin; index <= end; ++index)
> {
>     vector.erase(vector.begin() + index);
> }
> ```

В этом коде ошибка состоит в том, что индекс меняется на единицу, а поэтому удаление элементов проходит через один, ведь после удаления все элементы сдвинулись, а мы это не учитываем.

Конечно же, лучше использовать версию erase для удаления диапазона:

```
vector.erase(vector.begin() + begin, vector.begin() + (end + 1));
```

Но раз нужно удалять диапазон по одному элементу, и использовать индексы, то можно сделать так:

```
 for (int index = begin; index <= end; ++index)
 {
     //После удаления элементы сдвинуться,
     //и новый удаляемый элемент будет на той же позиции,
     //поэтому добавляем begin, а не index
     vector.erase(vector.begin() + begin);     
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Предыдущий автор описал проблемы кода, но с его решением я немного не согласен, потому что не совсем диапазон удаляется, а очищается одна и та же позиция, и без комментария на первый взгляд не совсем понятно, что происходит, если не задумываться, поэтому наверное более читабельно будет так:

```
for (int index = end; index >= begin; --index)
{
    vector.erase(vector.begin() + index);
}
```

В этом случае сходу видно, что происходит и смещение нас не задевает.

Но вообще это будет очень медленно, так как в векторе данные хранятся последовательно и каждый вызов erase будет переписывать остаток вектора. То есть при векторе на 10000 элементов, при удалении с 4 по 20й элемент, у вас вектор перепишется 17 раз. Это очень не рационально.

Лучшим решением по производительности было бы как-то так

```
end++;//легче работать с первым неудаляемым элементом 
int difference = end - begin;
if (difference <= 0) throw ... //обязательная обработка невалидного ввода(это для любого способа лучше добавить)
for (int i = end; i < vector.size(); i++)
{
    vector[i-difference] = vector[i];
}
vector.resize(vector.size() - difference);
```

Код не проверял, но он и не совершенен. Я просто саму идею показал, скорее всего это можно записать красивее используя библиотечные функции, но так зато понятно. Преимущество в том, что данные переписываются только один раз.

Comment: *"Лучшим решением по производительности было бы как-то так"* Это можно записать в одну строку (не считая проверки индексов): `vector.erase(vector.begin() + a, vector.begin() + (b+1));`, как уже предложили в соседнем ответе.